# PostgreSQL internals: Why is COUNT slow?

Tags: postgresql

Why does the time complexity of `COUNT` in postgresql (v9.6) appear to be as bad as it could get?
The following demonstrates that even without my machine under resource pressure ~3x more records causes it to take ~9x as long

i.e. **O(n2)**

```
   (397.0ms)   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cases"
=> 850219

   (3289.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cases"
=> 2577661
```

I would have expected it could take advantage of some indexes on the table but I guess this would only help estimate the rather than determine the count.

I imagine it's hard to improve but I'd be interested to find out why and if it's tuneable. Particularly with tables that are written to rarely I'm surprised the count can't be fully cached. What in the DB's internal structure makes it hard to include a `last_edited` timestamp in a table's metadata?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=postgresql+count+slow

Comment: Thank you @melpomene . The article is interesting but I'd still be interested in why the time complexity is not linear as a worst case. It also doesn't explain why the MVCC model can't be tweaked such that a guaranteed accurate number can be used when the table has not been written to for a few seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's nonlinear is probably because of [hint-bit writing on the first touch of the data](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hint_Bits), where *read* queries can do writes. Or it could be down to caching effects.

Usually counting of data without a suitable index is linear in cost. Try a properly repeated benchmark with warm-up.

PostgreSQL doesn't try to keep accurate counts on tables because it doesn't care that much. It keeps approximate statistics and figures that's good enough, if you want an exact count you'll perform one at the time. A count that's sometimes fast and sometimes slow would likely just be more confusing.

It *can't* keep a running total, because the table has *a different number of rows in it for different sessions at the same time*. Session 1 sees a table with 100 rows, but session 2 has inserted some so it has 205, and session 3 deleted some so it has 50. Session 6 started after session 5 committed a delete, so it sees fewer rows than session 1 does at the same instant.

It can't keep a "committed counter" + per-session counters, because rollbacks can occur in unpredictable orders, and what's "committed" varies depending on the session's snapshot. It'd have to do MVCC on a sort of side-table of table row counts, where it added a row with suitable xmin for each commit, and pruned them as transaction snapshots aged out. This would cost a fair bit in performance, for little benefit for most workloads.

Above all else, though, nobody's wanted it enough to add support for it. Either by funding the work, or doing the coding directly. It'd be a big job for little benefit.

What *has* been done is adding support for counting using index-only scans, which *greatly* speed up counts on the `PRIMARY KEY` or other indexed columns. They can use `VACUUM` and the visibility map to skip doing heap re-checks for visibility on pages that aren't freshly written to.

Comment: This is really interesting to someone coming from years of MS-SQL. I have always appreciated MVCC and the locking problems it relieves. I knew it would mean no easy counts during writing but I hadn't realised that when the last transaction completes, the table and indexes are still not pristine, at maximum internal consistency. That hint-bits article explains why not and it sounds like a great tradeoff. :)

Comment: I should say, yes once the table was static for a short while, count was 3x faster bringing it back to something like linear. This sounds like the index only scans you mentioned being allowed to do their thing.

Comment: Hint bits are related to PostgreSQL's MVCC implementation. Other MVCC implementations use other models, like separate map files for visibility info, visibility in indexes, etc. There are a bunch of different trade-offs.

Comment: Ah I couldn't claim to comment on the detailed tradeoffs of an implementation I know little about. I was speaking more in the abstract about the penny dropping as soon as I read this: "...confusing side effects of the implementation...which can result in heavy writes to a database table even though you're just reading from it."

This is work that could have been done immediately after writing (and would make a count easy to cache when write-inactive) but it sounds very sensible that it's deferred.

Comment: Vacuum usually gets around to setting hint bits pretty promptly, and will usually be triggered by heavy writes to a table. So it's usually only a concern when you're reading a table you heavily inserted/updated/deleted in an immediately prior transaction. Or if you've been playing with vacuum settings.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be caused by the narrowness of the cache which does not allow the retrieval of all the pages of the table or the index in memory and is obliged to scan the disk to do this.